# Norm of a functional with restricted domain

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $f$ be a continuous functional not cero in $Y$ and $g$ be a continuous functional such that $g(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$. For all $x\in X$ with $||x||=1$ there exist $y\in Y$ with $||y||=1$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq |f(y)|$.

$f$ is a extenstion of $f-g$ restricted to $Y$. Maybe I can do use of the theorem of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: This is false. Suppose $g\equiv 0$ and $f=0$ on $Y$. If we choose $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ then there is no $y\in Y$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq |f(y)|$.

Comment: And what if $f\neq 0$ in $Y$.

Comment: There exist some $w\in W$ such that $||w||=1$ and $f(w)\neq 0$. then if $x\notin W$ htere exist $n$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq n|f(w)|=|f(nw)|$ and $nw\in W$. Is this correct?

Comment: You forgot the condition $\|y\|=1$. So $nw$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case.

Take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=\{(0,t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $f(x):=x\cdot j$, $g(x):=2x\cdot i$ (so $gY=\{0\}$).

Let $x:=i=(1,0)$, then whether one chooses $y=(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$ (of unit norm), $$|f(x)-g(x)|=|0-2|=2>1=|f(y)|$$